# Font Awesome icons in Tabris.js

Tags: font-awesome, tabris-js

I have a tabris.js app and I would like to add some Font Awesome icons to it but I don't know how should I do it.

Anyone know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible.  There is an open issue for supporting custom fonts:

[Support custom Fonts #73](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/73)

And another one specifically for FontIcon widgets:

[Support FontIcon widget #698](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/698)

Comment: Thanks! This feature seems to be available now!